# custom order in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table1 with data like

```
group_name model_no    model_year   cost
mech        9000        2015         200
mech        9012        2015         300
mech        allmodelno  2015         500
cs           9000       2016         600
cs           9012       2016         400
cs          allmodelno  2016         1000
```

i want the output to be

```
group_name model_no    model_year   cost
    mech        9000        2015         200
    mech        9012        2015         300
    cs          9000        2016         600
    cs          9012        2016         400
    mech        allmodelno  2015         500
    cs          allmodelno  2016         1000
```

i tried 'select * from table1 order by model_no,model_yr'

am getting result as

```
      group_name model_no    model_year   cost
        mech        9000        2015         200
        cs          9000        2016         600
        mech       9012        2015         300
        cs          9012        2016         400
        mech        allmodelno  2015         500
        cs          allmodelno  2016         1000
```

which is wrong as the group_name is not coming as expected

if i use 'SELECT * from table1 order by group_name,model_no,model_year' then am getting result as

```
  group_name model_no    model_year   cost
    cs          9000        2016         600
    cs          9012        2016         400
    cs          allmodelno  2016         1000
    mech        9000        2015         200
    mech        9012         2015        300
    mech        allmodelno  2015         500
```

again the series is not as expected i want the final output to be in the below order

```
   group_name model_no    model_year   cost
    cs          9000        2016         600
    cs          9012        2016         400
    mech        9000        2015         200
    mech        9012        2015         300  
    cs          allmodelno  2016         1000
    mech        allmodelno  2015         500
```

can it be achived using order by or by any other way.please help me .thanks

**NOTE:'My logic explained in detail'** The allmodelno rows are the subtotal for the respective group_name and model_year.i want all the 'all model no ' record to be in the bottom of the table.

first i want the normal records(with out subtotal) to be listed in the top in order of the group_name,model_no,model_year

then i will get below output which **is table 'normal'**

```
group_name model_no    model_year   cost
cs          9000        2016         600
cs          9012        2016         400
mech        9000        2015         200
mech        9012        2015         300
```

then i want the subtotal in same order group_name,model_year as shown below .model_no is not taken here because it will be same 'allmodelno' for all the subtotal which is **table 'subtotal'**

```
    cs          allmodelno  2016         1000
    mech        allmodelno  2015         500
```

i union the both ,but the order should be in

```
 group_name model_no    model_year   cost
        cs          9000        2016         600
        cs          9012        2016         400
        mech        9000        2015         200
        mech        9012        2015         300  
        cs          allmodelno  2016         1000
        mech        allmodelno  2015         500
```

but am getting it all jumbled as

```
group_name model_no    model_year   cost
        cs          9000        2016         600
        cs          9012        2016         400
        cs          allmodelno  2016         1000
        mech        9000        2015         200
        mech        9012         2015        300
        mech        allmodelno  2015         500
```

Comment: i don´t know, but your expected output seems to have no order at all. It´s not ordered by any specifc column

Comment: Please explain the logic you need to use for ordering

Comment: That sample data is not enough to figure out what order you have in mind. Could please edit the question and explain what rules you want to apply?

Comment: Seems like your design is a bit odd. Probably you shouldn't store the allmodelno rows in the table.

Comment: output you ask for did not mean anything to me. what do you exactly want ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T
ORDER BY
  CASE
      WHEN model_name || model_no like '%allmodelno' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
  END,
  model_year
```

Comment: As a sidenode, keep in mind that, as `model_no` seems to be a `char`, it will create a lexographic ordering for the numbers and not a numeric ordering.

Comment: Yes, with data posted, I hope our OP has a patern for value and if he wants all model use always allmodelno

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` expression in the `ORDER BY` to sort allmodelno rows after the other rows:

```
select * from table1
order by case when model_no <> 'allmodelno' then 1 else 2 end,
         model_year, group_name, model_no;
```

Executes as:

```
SQL>select * from table1
SQL&order by case when model_no <> 'allmodelno' then 1 else 2 end,
SQL&         model_year, group_name, model_no;
group_name model_no    model_year        cost
========== ========== =========== ===========
mech       9000              2015         200
mech       9012              2015         300
cs         9000              2016         600
cs         9012              2016         400
mech       allmodelno        2015         500
cs         allmodelno        2016        1000

                  6 rows found
```

**Note:** Are those allmodelno rows stored in the table? Seems a bit risky. If a row is inserted/updated/deleted, the allmodelno row will be inconsistent. It's better to calculated the allmodelno run-time (e.g. using a view.)